# Noticed some gaps/rot on the chimney the other day, does this look like serious damage?

Tags: chimney, damage

New homeowner here, noticed some gaps/rot on the chimney the other day, does this look like serious damage? I'm not actually using the chimney but I'm worried about water damage from rain making it worse... does this look like an expensive fix?

[image]

Comment: Zoom out. Is that a flashed ridge behind the chimney shedding water around the chimney? If so, the design annoys me. The water is diverted to hit that piece of trim? That trim should stop an inch or two above the roof surface, and the valley flashing should shingle on top of flashing down the side of the chimney. I think I see a gap in the flashing inviting water to pour into the house. Clear that organic junk out of there and take another picture. Get a shot of the side of the chimney too.